# Insert offset method, in working code to copy data, to copy to next empty row

Tags: excel, vba

I am copying data from two workbooks to another workbook.

The code written by me works and serves the purpose.

I am having difficulty getting the syntax for using the offset method to copy to next empty row after the first paste.

```vb
With wsdly
    lrowdly = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A2:O" & lrowdly).ClearContents
    wsb.Range("A2:O" & lrowb).Copy .Range("A2")
End With
With wsdly
    lrowdly2 = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    lrowdly3 = lrowdly2 + 1
    wsn.Range("A2:O" & lrown).Copy .Range("A" & lrowdly3)
End With
```

Whole program.

```vb
Sub copy_bond_dat()
Dim wbb As Workbook
Dim wbn As Workbook
Dim wbdly As Workbook
Dim wsb As Worksheet
Dim wsn As Worksheet
Dim wsdly As Worksheet
Set wbb = Workbooks("BSE_BOND.xlsm")
Set wbn = Workbooks("NSE_BOND.xlsm")
Set wbdly = Workbooks("Dly_Debt_Trnx_2022_TMP.xlsx")
Set wsb = wbb.Worksheets("BSEDATA")
Set wsn = wbn.Worksheets("NSEDATA")
Set wsdly = wbdly.Worksheets("Dly_Debt_Trnx_2022_TMP")
Dim lrowb As Long
Dim lrown As Long
Dim lrowdly As Long
Dim lrowdly2 As Long
Dim lrowdly3 As Long
With wsb
    lrowb = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
End With
With wsn
    lrown = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
End With
With wsdly
    lrowdly = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A2:O" & lrowdly).ClearContents
    wsb.Range("A2:O" & lrowb).Copy .Range("A2")
End With
With wsdly
    lrowdly2 = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    lrowdly3 = lrowdly2 + 1
    wsn.Range("A2:O" & lrown).Copy .Range("A" & lrowdly3)
End With
wbdly.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the mentioned code lines to following code lines problem gets resolved.

```
With wsdly
    lrowdly = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A2:O" & lrowdly).ClearContents
    wsb.Range("A2:O" & lrowb).Copy .Range("A2")

    wsn.Range("A2:O" & lrown).Copy

    .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End With
```